# When is the integral of a function of two variables a continuous function?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose $(\Omega, \mu)$ is a finite measure space. Consider the non-negative functions $f(t,x)$ for $t\in[0,1]$ and $x \in \Omega$. Assume that for every $x\in\Omega$, $t \mapsto f(t,x)$ is continuous and for every $t \in [0,1]$, $x \mapsto f(t,x) \in L^1(\Omega)$. Is it true that $t \mapsto \int_\Omega f(t,x) \mu(dx)$ is continuous for $t \in [0,1]$?

This issue I am having is that when looking at
$$ \int_\Omega |f(t,x)-f(s,x)| \mu(dx) $$
we may only say that
$$ |f(t,x)-f(s,x)| \le \varepsilon \quad \text{when } |t-s| \le \delta(x,\varepsilon). $$
However I am having trouble finding a counterexample if the original statement is false.

In particular, I am interested when a centered and continuous Gaussian Process, $\{ X_t \}_{t\in[0,1]}$ is $L^2(\Omega)$ continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $\Omega =\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ where $n \in \Omega$ has mass $2^{-n}$ (in order to make $\Omega$ a probability space). We may think of function $f(t,n)$ of the type you describe as a sequence of continuous functions $f_n(t)$ on $[0,1]$ with the property that $\sum 2^{-n}f_n(t) < \infty$ for each $t \in [0,1]$. One easy way to make these sums converge is to make the functions $f_n$ have disjoint supports. On the other hand, there is no reason that $\sum 2^{-n}f_n$ should be a bounded function, let alone a continuous one. For instance, choose $f_n$ to be a continuous function supported in $(\frac{1}{n+1},\frac{1}{n})$ with $\sup_t f_n(t) = n 2^n$.

You can easily adapt this idea to get an analogous example where $\Omega=[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure.

Comment: Sorry, why is the example you gave not continuous when $f_n$ are continuous with support in $\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1},\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$? For example when $ t \in \left(\dfrac{1}{2},1\right)$ then $\sum 2^{-n}f_n(t)= (1/2)f_1(t)$ which is continuous?

Comment: The sum $f$ would be continuous on $(0,1]$, but not at $0$. One has $f(0)=0$ and $\limsup_{t \to 0} f(t) = \infty$.

Comment: I see, thank you!